# go to top of the page using jquery in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a ui theme called [nightsky](http://www.nightskyadmin.com/demo/template/dashboard.html)

After I scroll to the bottom of the page I want to go back to the top of the page.

What I have tried already in dev console :

1. `window.scrollTo(0, $("body").offset().top);`
2. `window.scrollTo(0, $("#main").offset().top();`
3. The following:

   ```
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#main').position().top },
       1000
   );
   ```

   seems to work in firefox not in chrome
4. `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0});`

I am looking for a code that can be executed in console! no on-click listeners etc...just few lines of code

Comment: `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0});` worked for me.

Comment: seems to work in firefox not in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery **[`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)**,

```
$(window).scrollTop(0)   //Or $('body').scrollTop(0)
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VEHQX/)**

Comment: did this work for you? doesnt seem to work in chrome

Comment: i know it works normally! but this is only in this theme http://www.nightskyadmin.com/demo/template/dashboard.html! there should be something wrong going couldnt figure out what it is!

Comment: I can't find the scrollTop code in your link. Worked for me in chrome.

Comment: there is no scrolltop code.try it in dev console! i mean pasting this code into developer console should take me to the top of the window isnt it?

Comment: ScrollTop does not work in console..Try in your JS code

Comment: Try adding this `html{  overflow:scroll
}` to css

Comment: this breaks the page i dont want another scrollerbar!

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use `<a href="#header">Go to top</a>`

Comment: first of all its a button i have to do some process on click of the button if there is an error go to the top of the page!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.top').on('click', function() {
     $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':'0px'},1000);
  });
});
```

here is demo link : http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/JWJ5N/13/

Comment: doesnt seem to work in chrome for this link http://www.nightskyadmin.com/demo/template/dashboard.html

Comment: In your page i didn't see the link which is use for click to go to top ? @TabraizAli

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<a href="#top">Click</a>
```